# ViewPager and 3 instantiates at once, video plays on its left image

Tags: android, android-viewpager, instantiation, android-pageradapter

I have a ViewPager in my Activity. I set it's adapter with PagerAdapter.
Items of Adapter are VideoViews and ImageViews. When I click on a thumbnail in another activity, ViewPager appears.
But, when page of an image is selected, video is playing in background because of default number of instantiations of ViewPager items (3)_left and right items of the active item.
Any ideas how to handle video playback while ViewPager is focused on image.
Here is how my Image is shown, the right item is a videoview and its MediaController.   [image: screenshot of my application]

Adapter class:

```
public class FullScreenViewAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
ActivityFullscreenSlideView _activity;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>> _media;
VideoView videosrc;
ImageView imageView;
MediaController mediaController;
View viewLayout;

public FullScreenViewAdapter(ActivityFullscreenSlideView activityFullscreenSlideView,
                             ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>> media) {
    this._activity = activityFullscreenSlideView;
    Collections.reverse(media);
    this._media = media;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return _media.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) _activity
            .getSystemService(G.context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (_media.get(position).get("type").equals(ActivityAppPage.IMAGE_TYPE)) {
        viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fullscreenview_image, container, false);
        imageView = (ImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.fullscreenimage);
        imageView.setImageResource(_media.get(position).get("src"));
    } else if (_media.get(position).get("type").equals(ActivityAppPage.VIDEO_TYPE)) {
        viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fullscreenview_video, container, false);
        videosrc = (VideoView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.video);
        Uri videoAddress = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + _activity.getPackageName() + "/"
                + _media.get(position).get("src"));
        videosrc.setVideoURI(videoAddress);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        _activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        videosrc.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(metrics.widthPixels, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mediaController = new MediaController(_activity);
            mediaController.setAnchorView(videosrc);
            videosrc.setMediaController(mediaController);
            videosrc.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mediaController.hide();
                }
            });
            videosrc.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    Log.i("LOG", "\nonprepared");
                    mediaController.show(0);
                    videosrc.start();
                }
            });
        }
    } else {
        videosrc.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Log.i("LOG", "\nonprepared OLD API");
                videosrc.start();
            }
        });
    }
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout);
    return viewLayout;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((LinearLayout) object);
}
```

My Activity that has ViewPager:

```
public class ActivityFullscreenSlideView extends AppCompatActivity
    implements View.OnClickListener {
private FullScreenViewAdapter adapter;
private ViewPager viewPager;
int dotsCount;
ImageView[] dots;
LinearLayout pager_indicator;
ArrayList<Integer> viewPagersArray;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>> media;
ActivityFullscreenSlideView thisActivity = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fullscreen_viewpager);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    viewPagersArray = (ArrayList<Integer>) i.getExtras().get("viewPagersArray");
    int position = i.getIntExtra("position", 0);
    media = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>>) i.getExtras().get("mAdapter.media");
    adapter = new FullScreenViewAdapter(ActivityFullscreenSlideView.this, media);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    int RtlPosition = media.size() - position - 1;
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(RtlPosition);
    pager_indicator = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewPagerCountDots);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(final int position) {
            if (adapter.mediaController != null)
                if (media.get(position).get("type").equals(ActivityAppPage.IMAGE_TYPE)) {
                    Log.i("LOG", "Image Selected");
                    adapter.mediaController.hide();
                    adapter.videosrc.stopPlayback();
                } else if (media.get(position).get("type").equals(ActivityAppPage.VIDEO_TYPE)) {
                    Log.i("LOG", "Video Selected");
                    adapter.mediaController.show(0);
                }
            for (int i = 0; i < dotsCount; i++) {
                dots[i].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nonselecteditem_dot));
            }
            dots[position].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selecteditem_dot));
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });
    setUiPageViewController(RtlPosition);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found what I had to do. I just used "setOnFocusChangeListener" in my Adapter.

```
videosrc.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if (hasFocus)
                        videosrc.start();
                    else
                        videosrc.stopPlayback();
                }
            });
```

And also I removed "OnPreparedListener".

Answer (score 0):

Remove all other coding related to play video when the page is active. Only make these changes in adaptive, it's working for me.

```
videosrc.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus)
                    ((VideoView)v.findViewById(R.id.videoView).start();
                else
                    ((VideoView)v.findViewById(R.id.videoView).pause();
       });
```